# Bootstrap navbar is not expanding

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a proper navbar on bootstrap but it just doesn't expand in mobile version. Clicking on the button just doesn't do anything.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-left">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Your music recommender</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

To note, I'm using Angular with Boostrap

Answer (score 0):

Without further explanation, it's hard to understand what's happening.. but there are a few reasons that it MIGHT be happening.

1 - Be sure that you put the CSS link inside your < head >

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

2 - Put the  that right before you close your < body > tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

in head tag